# How to only remove one character if there are two consecutive characters in the string (using regex)

Tags: java, regex, nested-lists

I have a list of list of Characters like this : [[P, A, H, N, ,], [A, P, L, S, I, I, G, ,], [Y, I, R]].

Output *expected* as a *String* of every character in the list of list of Characters

> Output expected: "**PAHN,APLSIIG,YIR".**

> **My code**

```
String str = "";
```

```
//code#1
for(int j=0; j<list.size(); j++){
   str += Arrays.toString(list.get(j).toArray(new Character[0])).replaceAll("[\\]\\[,]", 
   "").replaceAll(" ", "");
}
```

**str in code#1** :  "PAHNAPLSIIGYIR"

> *List to a String*

`String str = "";`

```
//code#2, converts a list into String
for(int j=0; j<list.size(); j++){
   str += Arrays.toString(list.get(j).toArray(new Character[0])).replaceAll(" ", "");
}
```

**str in code#2** : [P,A,H,N,,][A,P,L,S,I,I,G,,][Y,I,R]

Check this code to understand better:
[https://onecompiler.com/java/3xm55ywr6][1]

> *My Problem*

String in code#2 have two consecutive ',' characters, as can be seen after characters 'N' and 'G', how to just replace only one ',' character if there are two ',' coming together???

Comment: Please include the definition for the list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to flat your lists

```
private static String flatLists(List<List<String>> asList) {
        return asList.stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .filter(s -> !s.equals(" "))
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
PAHNAPLSIIGYIR
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understood your question

However, if your goal is to remove all the commas, spaces, and square brackets, then the following regular expression should work

```regex
[\[\],\s]
```

You can test it here

https://regex101.com/r/j0OIOH/1